# Realtime planetary gravity maps?

Tags: mapping, gravity

I'm trying to find maps of realtime (or at least periodically updated / semi-realtime) gravity maps of Earth.

I was hoping that [GOCE](https://earth.esa.int/web/guest/missions/esa-operational-eo-missions/goce) might have something like this available, but I've been hitting a wall.

Any such maps available?

Answer (score 5):

For sure this is not available.

1. To create those maps takes several dozens Earth orbits by GOCE (one orbit ~90 minutes) and possibly many more to bring up the signal to noise
2. Which gravitational features would you expect to vary significantly on any human timescale, so that creating such a scan would make sense?

This does not mean however, that no gravitational changes over time can be detected. [ESA produced a video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Dyq6kGKPQ5g) visualising data that showcases how GRACE and GOCE worked to produce ~10 snapshots per year from 2009-2012 to measure Antarctic ice loss. So continuing your search along those lines will surely lead to positive results.

Comment: These do change much more than you realize and with frequency. I have also heard that such sources do exist within the scientific community. I’ll have to make some more inquires to those circles from whence this info came.

Comment: @ylluminate: Well, surely Earth's gravitational signal changes all the time. Any proton and electron carries mass, so don't give me a "These do change much more than you realize and with frequency". But that doesn't mean we have the precision and sensitivtiy to measure that. You're free to google this by yourself. But if state of the art observatories like GOCE can't do it, nothing can.